# What shapes can be composed of scaled copies of themselves, with no intersection?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, fractals

A square can be subdivided into 4 squares, each scaled by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$.

A right-angled triangle can generally be subdivided into 2 similar triangles of different size.

What other shapes, possibly fractal, of any topological dimension, may be subdivided into finitely or infinitely many similar shapes, *at least two of which are scaled by a different factor*?

What shapes can be composed of differently scaled copies of themselves, with no intersection?

Comment: You can read into this if you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile This shows there are many different shapes who can be made up of scaled copies of themselves and they can't easily be put into one list.

Comment: If you want only different sized copies then you could look into "Squaring the Square": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square

Answer (score 1):

Most of these kinds of shapes are in the category of "Rep-tiles" (Repeatable tiles). You can read into this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile) on them if you want. This shows there are many different shapes who can be made up of scaled copies of themselves and they can't easily be put into one list. Those include simple shapes like squares and triangles but also some fractals and other more complex shapes.

But here are a few interesting examples:

**Squares.**

Shapes made up of multiple squares with the same size which you can create bigger squares out of.

"L-shape", used for the L-substitution.

[image: L-substitution]
[image: Square Reps1]
[image: Square Reps2]
[image: Square Reps3]

**Triangles.**

The same thing but with equilateral triangles (if you can create a big triangle, you can also create the same shape but bigger).

[image: Triangle Reps1]
[image: Triangle Reps2]

**Others.**

[image: rep1]
[image: rep2]
[image: rep3]
[image: rep4]

**Fractals.**

Dragon Curve:

[image: fractal1]

Elongated Koch Snowflake:

[image: fractal2]

Sierpinski Carpet:

[image: fractal3]

Comment: Thanks, but how do I adapt the tiling, such that each tile is of a different size? In this case, I need at least two of the component tiles to be scaled by different factors.

Comment: @Dash-Eight8Hyphen-8 Oh, then I think I misunderstood your question. An example of making a shape up of only differently sized copies would be "Squaring the Square": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square This can't be done with just any shape that can be made up of itself and is generally very difficult to solve.